# Clojure om next multiple print-method exception

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, om

I am trying to build server-side rendering for `om.next` (1.0.0-alpha47). At some point I have to create a reconciler from Clojure:

```
 (om/reconciler {})

 (om/reconciler
  {:state     (atom {})
   :normalize true
   :parser    (om/parser {})})
```

However evaluating any of these in my REPL gives:

> Unhandled java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    Multiple methods in
>   multimethod 'print-method' match dispatch value: class
>   om.next.Reconciler -> interface clojure.lang.IDeref and interface
>   clojure.lang.IRecord, and neither is preferred

How do I fix that?

Comment: Is this https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/prefer-method helpful?

Comment: @KobbyPemson that looks useful though I wouldn't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to this solution via trial and error:

```
(prefer-method print-method clojure.lang.IPersistentMap clojure.lang.IDeref)
```

This seems to solve the conflict, sorry that I can't explain any details.